# How can I pass an array value to an overloaded method?

Tags: java

I have been tasked with creating a pair of overloaded methods which takes in some values and multiplies them. I decided to use an array to keep things tidy but my methods do not seem to be operating as expected. How can I pass an array value to an overloaded method?

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

class Lab8Ex4 {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        //Declare Variables
        int[] numbers = new int[5] ;

        //Setup a scanner.
        Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in ) ;

        ///////////////////
        //Get User Input//
        ///////////////////

        for ( int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++ ) {
            System.out.println ( "Please enter a number: " ) ;
            numbers[j] = scan.nextInt() ;
        }

        //Call the first method
        multiply ( numbers[0], numbers[1] );
        //Call the second method
        multiply ( numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4] );
    }

    //Overloaded Method - Multiplication of two numbers.
    static int multiply ( int a, int b ) {
        int sum = a * b ;
        return sum ;
    }

    //Overloaded Method - Multiplication of three numbers.
    static int multiply ( int a, int b, int c ) {
        int sum = a * b * c ;
        return sum ;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work as expected? What did you expect to happen? Both methods get called and calculate a result, but you don't use the result.

Comment: (Also, the variable `sum` should be called `product`)

Comment: As @ModusTollens says, your methods are called but you do nothing with them. Try just to log the result, e.g. `System.out.println("First multiply result is: "+ multiply ( numbers[0], numbers[1] ));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is this,

```
static int multiply(int... values) {
    int product = 1;

    for(int v : values) {
        product *= v;
    }

    return product;
}
```

And to call it,

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

System.out.println(multiply(a));
System.out.println(multiply(a, b));
System.out.println(multiply(a, b, c));
```